# Erlang: How to plug Elvis style check to rebar3 project properly?

Tags: erlang, coding-style

I'm adding [Elvis](https://github.com/inaka/elvis) check style to Erlang project built with rebar3.

Initially I've found rebar3_lint plugin for this. But then it appeared to use some old version of Elvis and fails not very graciously on errors.

Then after some play I attached elvis directly as a test dependency and then calling it with pre_hook and erlang code line:

```
{profiles, [
  {test, [
    {deps, [
      {elvis_core,
       {git, "https://github.com/inaka/elvis_core",
        {branch, "master"}}}
     ]},
    {pre_hooks, [{compile, 
     "erl -pa _build/test/lib/*/ebin -noshell -eval 'init:stop(case elvis_core:rock() of ok -> 0; _ -> 1 end)'"}]}
  ]},
]}
```

This works nicely, though looks awkward.

So is there any more "proper" way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, rebar3_lint was recently updated. https://github.com/project-fifo/rebar3_lint